# Change the content of a data type on the fly

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Inside my **Razor** file I am using:

```
<div>
    @Umbraco.Field("myText")
</div>
```

as to get and display the content of `myText` property. The actual content of myText which is a `Textstring`, is:

```
<a href="/main/somefile"> Hello </a>
```

What I want to do is to change on the fly, the path inside href when calling myText from Razor. For example, I want sometimes **Hello** hyperlink to drive to `/main/somefile` and some other times to `/main/otherfile`. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it without making a new property for the new text, if it's on the same document.

So you have to make more properties like

@myText-1
@myText-2

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some information. I'm assuming you want to change the link depending on some condition?

What I would do is simply change your input text in Umbraco to be something like:

`<a href="{link}"> Hello </a>`

Then I would get the value of the property on the current page and simply replace the string `{link}` with whatever link should be inserted here, based on the condition and save that in a variable. Then output that variable with the replaced link in your template.

How to get a value from the current page: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/ipublishedcontent/Properties#model-content-getpropertyvalue-string)

Another (prettier) approach would be to create a Html helper that wraps this functionality: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs#creating-html-helpers-with-static-methods

Example:

`@{
    var myText = Model.GetPropertyValue("myText").ToString();
    if (something)
    {
        myText = myText.Replace("{link}", "somefile");
    }
    else
    {
        myText = myText.Replace("{link}", "someotherfile");
    }
    @myText
}`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get into your point. In that case, I need to pass a value to  @Umbraco.Field("myText") as for `link` to get it (the value). How? Could you provide some code please?

Comment: Added a code example above... you could do something like that. Get the value, replace with what you need based on a condition and then print the value using @myText

Comment: Thank you for the code. However, `Model.GetPropertyValue` does not work. I have to write `Model.Content.GetPropertyValue` . Unfortunately, even the last one does not work and I am getting the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.